# How to convert for of loop into a for loop to solve the ESLint error

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I convert a for of loop into a for loop?
This is so that I can avoid/ solve the eslint error message.I have tried googling, but the solution I am getting is to disable/configure eslint. Help me understand what I'm missing.
here is the error message.
**"  error  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations "**

here is my working code using the for of.

```
let str = '';
const arr = [];
for (const person of featuredObject) {
  str = `        
    <div class="portfolio"><img src=${person.image} alt="#"></div>
    <div class="card-one">
        <h3 class="name">${person.Name}</h3>
        <p class="myTitle">${person.title}</p>
        <p class="myDescription">${person.description}</p>
    </div>
</div>`;
  arr.push(str);
}
```

here is my failed implementation of the for loop.

```
let str = '';
const person = '';
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < featuredObject.length; i += 1) {
  str= `
    <div class="portfolio"><img src=${person.image} alt="#"></div>
    <div class="card-one">
        <h3 class="name">${person.Name}</h3>
        <p class="myTitle">${person.title}</p>
        <p class="myDescription">${person.description}</p>
    </div>
</div>`;
  arr.push(str);
}
```

Comment: Use `${featuredObject[i]. ...}`instead of `${person. ...}`.

Comment: thanks, @collapser, worked very fast and well. I I also got some good points off maps, I think I'll research more on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let str = "";
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < featuredObject.length; i += 1) {
  const person = featuredObject[i];
  str = `
    <div class="portfolio"><img src=${person.image} alt="#"></div>
    <div class="card-one">
        <h3 class="name">${person.Name}</h3>
        <p class="myTitle">${person.title}</p>
        <p class="myDescription">${person.description}</p>
    </div>
  </div>`;
  arr.push(str);
}
```

Better way

```
const arr = featuredObject.map((person) => {
  const str = `
    <div class="portfolio"><img src=${person.image} alt="#"></div>
    <div class="card-one">
        <h3 class="name">${person.Name}</h3>
        <p class="myTitle">${person.title}</p>
        <p class="myDescription">${person.description}</p>
    </div>
  </div>`;
  return str;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In for of loop in person is a element of featuredObject, so it as all properties but in for loop person is string not an element featuredObject.
I am using div element because if you append a element into another element it preserve all event listener but when you append something into innerHTML it removes all event listener.

```
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < featuredObject.length; i++) {
  const person = featuredObject[i];
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "portfolio");
  div.innerHTML = `
    <img src=${person.image} alt="#"></div>
    <div class="card-one">
        <h3 class="name">${person.Name}</h3>
        <p class="myTitle">${person.title}</p>
        <p class="myDescription">${person.description}</p>
    </div>`;
  arr.push(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate the new array.

```js
const arr = featuredObject.map((person) => `
    <div class="portfolio"><img src=${person.image} alt="#"></div>
    <div class="card-one">
        <h3 class="name">${person.Name}</h3>
        <p class="myTitle">${person.title}</p>
        <p class="myDescription">${person.description}</p>
    </div>
</div>`);
```